# Horizontal scroll than vertical scroll if horizontal content ends

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to achieve vertical scroll if horizontal scroll ends.

I have 2 div one below the other .The first one contains the content  which can be scrolled horizontally.(I have done this part) now I am stuck at how to make it scroll vertically to the 2nd div which is just below the 1st div after the content of 1st div ends.

I need some guidance to achieve this any plugin or code will help . i will do it myself I just need the path to follow.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
       <html>
      <head>
 <title></title>

<style type="text/css">
    *{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    body,html{
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .div{
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;

    }
    .red{
        background-color: red;
    }
    .green{
        background-color: green;
    }
    .wrapper{

            overflow-x:hidden;
    }
    .insideWrapper{
        background: black;
        height: 400px;
        width: 3300px;
        overflow-x: visible;
        overflow-x: scroll;
        margin: 135px 0;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;

        }
       .inside{
          width: 200px;
          height: 200px;
          background-color: rebeccapurple;
          display: inline-block
        }
       .inside:nth-child(2n){
        background-color: mediumseagreen;
        }
         .inside:nth-child(3n+1){
        background-color: yellow;
        }
       .insideWrapper::-webkit-scrollbar {
      width: 0px;
        }

    </style>
    </head>
  <body>


  <div class="wrapper red div">
      <div class=" insideWrapper">
     <div class=" inside"></div>
     <div class=" inside"></div>
      <div class=" inside"></div>
<div class=" inside"></div>
<div class=" inside"></div>
<div class=" inside"></div>
<div class=" inside"></div>
<div class=" inside"></div><div class=" inside"></div>
<div class=" inside"></div>
<div class=" inside"></div>
<div class=" inside"></div><div class=" inside"></div>
<div class=" inside"></div>
<div class=" inside"></div>
<div class=" inside"></div>
<div class=" inside"></div>
<div class=" inside"></div>
<div class=" inside"></div>
<div class=" inside"></div><div class=" inside"></div>
<div class=" inside"></div>
<div class=" inside"></div>
<div class=" inside"></div><div class=" inside"></div>
<div class=" inside"></div>
<div class=" inside"></div>
<div class=" inside"></div><div class=" inside"></div>
<div class=" inside"></div>
<div class=" inside"></div>
<div class=" inside"></div><div class=" inside"></div>
<div class=" inside"></div>
<div class=" inside"></div>
<div class=" inside"></div><div class=" inside"></div>
<div class=" inside"></div>
<div class=" inside"></div>
  <div class=" inside"></div>

   </div>


 </div>

  <div class="green div"></div>
      <script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js?ver=1.3.2'>   </script>
 <script type='text/javascript'    src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-  mousewheel/3.1.13/jquery.mousewheel.js'></script>

 <script type="text/javascript">

   $(document).ready(function(){


      $(".insideWrapper").mousewheel(function(event, delta) {

       this.scrollLeft -= (delta * 30);

     event.preventDefault();

   });

  });




 </script> 
 </body>
```

Comment: could you please add your code too?

Comment: added the code @kukkuz